# JSON Cannot viewed in Listview, Getting Error, Unterminated Exceptions

Tags: android, json, android-listview

I want to show data in listview and I am getting error. How to Show data in ListView.
 THis is my newstring variable

```
      {"JSONDataResult":"{"contacts":[{"country":"Pakistan","sunrise":1381107633,"sunset":1381149604}]}"}
```

and my error is in this line after this line i got exception in code

```
     JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(newString);
```

and my error in logcat is

```
     01-15 15:39:17.050: W/System.err(731): org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 22 of {"JSONDataResult":"{"contacts":[{"country":"Pakistan","sunrise":1381107633,"sunset":1381149604}]}"}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: your json is not valid ...

Comment: here is a great tool to check the validity of your Json especially later if you work with bigger json data https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

valid your JSON, [using this](http://jsonlint.com/) you had a lingering `"`

```
{
    "JSONDataResult": {
        "contacts": [
            {
                "country": "Pakistan",
                "sunrise": 1381107633,
                "sunset": 1381149604
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Why it is not valid .. Is that compulsory to give space in it

Comment: There was a linguering `"` here `"JSONDataResult": "{` <- that last `"`before the `{` should not be there :)

Answer (score 1):

try to use this structure

```
{"JSONDataResult":[{"Name":"name1"},{"Name":"name2"}]}
```

here "JSONDataResult" is an arrayObject and "Name" is an Object